# git diffrence between clone repo and clone rep.git

Tags: git, github

is there any difference between:

```
git clone git://github.com/randomrep
```

and

```
git clone git://github.com/randomrep.git
```

I've seen both seams to work and I've seen both types in instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github will allow you to clone from both locations.  There should be no differences, but be aware that isn't a normal standard for remote git repositories to accept either.  In my opinion, It would be better to use the uri that Github reports on the website which always includes the .git extension.  That way you can be more sure that the nonstandard behavior won't disappear in the future.

Some Git custom client applications will also forceably add .git to the end of url's if the first isn't found but again that is not standard behavior with the normal git client.